# std::is_const & Co with value-type wrappers as std::reference_wrapper

Tags: c++, type-traits

This might be a bit of an academic example (in the sense that I don't see it having a real use case as-is), but I have come across this line of thought a couple of times without coming up with a satisfying answer.

For the sake of argument, let's suppose that I have a template function that I want to behave differently depending on whether the passed value is const or not. A very simple example might be

```
template< typename T > void print_constness(T&& t) {
    if constexpr (std::is_const_v< decltype(t) >) {
        std::cout << "T is const\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "T is NOT const\n";
    }
}
```

If I pass a mutable reference to this function, it will correctly detect it as non-const. If I pass a const reference to it, then it correctly detects it as const (provided I can prevent the function from making a copy, e.g. by deleting the copy constructor).

Conceptually, `std::reference_wrapper< T >` is supposed to represent the same type as `const T &`. Therefore, one might expect that the result from passing a `const T` to that function is the same as passing a `std::reference< const T >`.

But this is not the case, since the wrapper itself is not const. However, for practical purposes, it is. Consider e.g. a template function that has to call a const or non-const overload of a function. When passed a `std::reference_wrapper< const T >`, it will pass it to the non-const overload and as soon as that tries to access the reference the compiler will complain (rightfully so).

(Note that I deliberately ignored that you can overload on the constness of your argument - my above example shall only serve as an illustration).

My question is: How to detect and in further steps modify constness of value-type wrappers such as `std::reference_wrapper` when the standard `std::is_const`, `std::add_const` and `std::remove_const` clearly don't work?

Is there a generic/standard solution to this problem or would it require implementing custom `is_const`, ... traits that specialize on the value wrappers that one expects to encounter?
If so: is it perhaps possible for the implementers of such wrappers to specialize the std type traits so they produce the (semantically) expected result? I kinda expect this to be forbidden...

Comment: Specialization in `std` is forbidden (but exceptions). `std::is_const` is not one of those exceptions.

Comment: You have to write your own trait for your purpose (in the same way is `std::span<const int>` and/or `const std::span<int>` `const` from your point of view (or simply `const T*` versus `T*const`

Answer (score 2):

If you have C++20, there's [`std::unwrap_reference`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/unwrap_reference):

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
using remove_reference_and_wrapper_t =
    std::remove_reference_t<std::unwrap_reference_t<std::remove_reference_t<T>>>;

template<typename T>
constexpr static bool is_semantically_const_v =
    std::is_const_v<remove_reference_and_wrapper_t<T>>;

static_assert(is_semantically_const_v<const int>);
static_assert(is_semantically_const_v<const int&>);
static_assert(is_semantically_const_v<const int&&>);
static_assert(!is_semantically_const_v<int>);
static_assert(!is_semantically_const_v<int&>);
static_assert(!is_semantically_const_v<int&&>);
static_assert(is_semantically_const_v<std::reference_wrapper<const int>>);
static_assert(!is_semantically_const_v<std::reference_wrapper<int>>);
```

It's a little unwieldy, but it works.

You can then use the type returned by `remove_reference_and_wrapper_t` to further manipulate the object; i.e., get a reference to the actual object:

```
remove_reference_and_wrapper_t<decltype(t)>& underlying = t;
```

Comment: Or in other words: there is no way to make this work with only the standard type_traits related to constness. It will always require a dedicated trait or type manipulation for the type in question. Too bad. But thanks anyway!